# Unable to access bootstrap 'defines' within View

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am in the process of upgrading from CakePHP 2.1 to 2.3, however I seem unable to reference bootstrap.php defines from within a view file.

bootstrap.php:

```
define('MODEL_VARIABLE_ID_YES', 1);
```

View File:

```
if($model['Model']['variable_id'] == MODEL_VARIABLE_ID_YES)
{
     show something...
}
else
{
    show something else...
}
```

Is this something that has been removed intentionally, or is there some other way to access these defines?

Comment: Are you getting an error or is your `if/else` not behaving as expected? Is debug mode on? Tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @Ross I am getting the error:
Use of undefined constant MODEL_VARIABLE_ID_YES - assumed 'MODEL_VARIABLE_ID_YES'. Yes, I have tried clearing the cache.

Comment: I actually seem to be unable to access these defines in my AppController either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel like a right idiot.
The issue was related to CakePHP caching, I use memcache and had broken my PHP installation of memcache (when updating PHP earlier). This was causing CakePHP to fire an error about the caching, then when it tried to display the error in my default.ctp file, it errored again because that file contains a define from bootstrap.php, which must not have loaded due to the cache engine issue.